# how to find a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac{y}{ f(x)})=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

> $$\frac{d^2w}{dx^2}+2\frac{dw}{dx}+5w=-5x^2-4x-2$$
>
> Given that $$y=\frac{1}{w}$$

---

> Where The particular solution (I found) is :

$$w=e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)-x^2$$

---

> The general solution (I found) :

$w=e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)$$

---

**Quesion:**

> Find a function $f(x)$ such that:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac{y}{ f(x)})=1$$

I have no idea how to find a function $f(x)$

When $x\to \infty$ Then:

Particular solution: $w \to 1 - (\infty)^2$

General solution: $w \to 1$

I don't know which one to pick (work with), general or particular? And also I mainly don't know how to  find $f(x)$

---

If it's particular solution:

So $$y=\frac{1}{w} \implies \frac{1}{\infty} \implies y=0$$

how do I proceed?

---

If it's G.S:

$$y=\frac {1}{1} =1$$

How to proceed to find $f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} (\frac{y}{ f(x)})=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{wf(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{(e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)-x^2)f(x)}$$

What about $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$, then:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{(e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)-x^2)f(x)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{(e^{-x}(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)-x^2)(-\frac{1}{x^2})}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{-(e^{-x}/x^2(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x)+1}$$

When $x \to \infty$ then $-(e^{-x}/x^2(C \cos 2x+ E \sin 2x) \to 0$, so:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{y}=1$$